# React inline styles not reverting back to more general properties when removing more specific properties

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, inline-styles

I have a react component which uses inline styles and allows additional override styles to be passed as props.

```js
function Input(props) {
  return (
    <input
      style={{
        borderRadius: 10,
        border: '2px solid white',
        ...props.style,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

In one specific use-case of the component, I want to remove the bottom border and get rid of the border radius on the two bottom corners of the component when some `condition` is met:

```js
<Input
  style={!condition ? {} : {
    borderBottom: 0,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
  }}
/>
```

This works as expected both on initial render, and once the condition is updated to true, however, once the condition is reverted back to false, the bottom border radius stays 0 rather than reverting back to the 10px specified by the borderRadius.

What seems to be happening, is once the bottom border radii are set to 0, instead of keeping `borderRadius` and overriding it with the more specific properties I set in the conditional style, react is instead replacing `borderRadius` with `borderTopLeftRadius` and `borderTopRightRadius` (i.e. the ones that **weren't** set in the conditional style).

After condition is toggled back to false this persists, rather than `borderRadius` being set on the element again even though the conditional style is now empty.

Is there any way around this other than having to reset the initial values in the falsy branch of the condition?  I don't want the initial values of the Input style to need to be known outside of the Input function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the style to the child component, you can pass a condition and change the style depending on its value, like this:

```
function Input({ condition }) {
  return (
    <input
      style={{
        background: "red",
        borderRadius: `${condition ? "10px" : "10px 10px 0 0px"}`,
        border: "2px solid white",
        borderBottom: `${condition ? "0" : "2"}px solid white`,
      }}
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCondition(prev => !prev)}>Change</button>
      <Input condition={condition} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Edit:**

The anothere way I could think of is by using custom libraly [styled-compenents](https://styled-components.com/) where you could do somethin like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

const CustomInput = styled.input`
  background: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  ${(props) => props.additionalStyles}
`;

function Input({ additionalStyles }) {
  return <CustomInput additionalStyles={additionalStyles} />;
}

function App() {
  const [condition, setCondition] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setCondition((prev) => !prev)}>Change</button>
      <Input
        additionalStyles={
          !condition ? ""
          : css`
            border-bottom: 0;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
          `
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here you can find more about css function from styled-components: [Link](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#css)

Comment: I was hoping to not have to do that, as the Input is a pretty standard component and the conditional styling of it is pretty bespoke to that one use-case.  Could imagine Input blowing up with all sorts of conditionals and what not as additional use-cases would be needed.